# how to inflate the navigation drawer with the user data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The below code help me inflate the username on the drawer menu but the App crash when the user logout is the a better way to retrieved the user data from fire store and not get app crash error when the user log out

```
  private void DatabaseMethod(String userId) {

        final DocumentReference documentReference =  fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                assert documentSnapshot != null;
                if(documentSnapshot.getString("fullName")!=null){
                    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                    TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    navUsername.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fullName"));


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my Total code just in case you will like to view the entire code

```
 package com.example.entertainmentlab;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declaring Variable

    TextView username;
   private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
   private String userId;
    private FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;


    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();




        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_trending, R.id.nav_audio, R.id.nav_videos,R.id.nav_store,R.id.nav_setting)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        //set the toolbar text to this color
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorelabGold));

      //set the NavigationView text color
      navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(218,165,32)));

      navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(218,165,32)));
      navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,33,33));
      //set the  Color of the navigationView List Menu
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

        MenuItem tools= menu.findItem(R.id.more);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
        s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance44), 0, s.length(), 0);
        tools.setTitle(s);


        userId = Objects.requireNonNull(fAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();


        
//inflate the drawer 
   DatabaseMethod(userId);
//sign the user out 
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

               fAuth.signOut();
               
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                //clear the onBackPress Data
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });


 }
//Here is the code I am talking about but the app crash when the user logout
    private void DatabaseMethod(String userId) {

        final DocumentReference documentReference =  fStore.collection("users").document(userId);

        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                assert documentSnapshot != null;
                if(documentSnapshot.getString("fullName")!=null){
                    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                    TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    navUsername.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fullName"));


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Here is the crash log cat

```
2021-02-13 17:53:27.739 3204-3204/? I/ntertainmentla: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-02-13 17:53:27.984 3204-3204/? E/ntertainmentla: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-13 17:53:29.532 3204-3204/ I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2021-02-13 17:53:29.532 3204-3204/ I/MultiDex: Installing application
2021-02-13 17:53:29.533 3204-3204/ I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.535 3204-3204/ I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.transsion.theme.icon
2021-02-13 17:53:29.672 3204-3297/ W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.679 3204-3204/ D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.680 3204-3204/ D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.681 3204-3204/ D/FirebaseApp: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.681 3204-3204/ I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-02-13 17:53:29.769 3204-3303/ W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.796 3204-3303/ I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
2021-02-13 17:53:29.797 3204-3303/ I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2021-02-13 17:53:30.046 3204-3204/ W/ntertainmentla: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.049 3204-3204/ W/ntertainmentla: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.233 3204-3204/ D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels +
2021-02-13 17:53:30.256 3204-3204/ D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-02-13 17:53:30.301 3204-3204/ I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@c8661e1
2021-02-13 17:53:30.310 3204-3204/ D/TouchScreenHelper: --getInstance()
2021-02-13 17:53:30.310 3204-3204/ D/TouchScreenHelper: --getInstance()  com.transsion.view.TouchScreenHelperImpl
2021-02-13 17:53:30.311 3204-3204/ I/TouchScreenHelperImpl: constructed in 
2021-02-13 17:53:30.363 3204-3204/ D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2021-02-13 17:53:30.381 3204-3204/ V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@f263b1d, this = DecorView@eb83192[MainActivity]
2021-02-13 17:53:30.461 3204-3306/ I/GPUD: @gpudInitialize: successfully initialized with GL, dbg=0 mmdump_dbg=0 mmpath_dbg=0
2021-02-13 17:53:30.478 3204-3306/ E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.514 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x9cd83800,api=1)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.520 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x9cd83800,bufferCount=3)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.521 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x9cd83800)
2021-02-13 17:53:30.566 3204-3306/ W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-02-13 17:53:30.577 3204-3306/ E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2021-02-13 17:53:35.418 3204-3204/ W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3f1258d
2021-02-13 17:53:36.241 3204-3204/ V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@89356e4[]
2021-02-13 17:53:36.253 3204-3204/ D/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2021-02-13 17:53:36.263 3204-3204/ V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@8540713, this = DecorView@89356e4[WelcomeActivity]
2021-02-13 17:53:36.288 3204-3204/ V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@f263b1d, this = DecorView@eb83192[MainActivity]
2021-02-13 17:53:36.308 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x9cd83800,api=1)
2021-02-13 17:53:36.311 3204-3204/ D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@eb83192[MainActivity]
2021-02-13 17:53:36.418 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x9cd83800,api=1)
2021-02-13 17:53:36.432 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x9cd83800,bufferCount=3)
2021-02-13 17:53:36.435 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x9cd83800)
2021-02-13 17:53:36.467 3204-3306/ I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 2, oppidx_max 2, oppidx_min 0
2021-02-13 17:53:36.467 3204-3306/ I/chatty: uid=10206() RenderThread identical 1 line
2021-02-13 17:53:36.467 3204-3306/ I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 2, oppidx_max 2, oppidx_min 0
2021-02-13 17:53:40.475 3204-3306/ D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x9cd83800,api=1)
2021-02-13 17:53:40.498 3204-3204/ V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@8540713, this = DecorView@89356e4[WelcomeActivity]
```

Comment: please add the crash logcat report

Comment: @Zain I just added it

Comment: You called `startActivity(intent);` twice when you sign out can you remove the first one and check.. please let me know the result to think of another potential issues

Comment: Glad that could help.. I have posted it as an answer thanks to accept it so that it probably help others in the future

Comment: @Zain I didn't accept your answer because the solution only show the Login page for a few seconds then the behave the same way it did again before you try solving it please forgive my inconvenience in proper observation before I conclude that it work , to be simple it still not working

Comment: @Zain when I comment out the first code I show before the entire code it works properly but when I uncomment it boom it go back to normal throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You called `startActivity(intent);` twice when you the user signs out .. You need to remove the first one.

```
//sign the user out 
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

           fAuth.signOut();
           
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);

            //clear the onBackPress Data
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was when the user signout firebase set the document snapshot to null to solve it I just catch that error however this might not be a proper solution but it work for now

```
try {
                        String name = documentSnapshot.getString("fullName");
                        navUsername.setText(name);
                    }catch (Exception a){
                   // throw error and continue
                    }
```